# Exposing Spring Boot actuator endpoints via Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have an Spring Boot App with this configuration running on the port 8081:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig { // extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private final AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    public WebSecurityConfig(JwtUtils jwtUtils,
                             UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService,
                             AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler) {

        this.jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter(jwtUtils, userDetailsService);
    }



    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
 }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/actuator/metrics").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/languages").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/actuator/health").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/sendMailOTP").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/messages/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/socialSignin").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/geoDetails").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/legalinfo/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/legalinfo/*").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/legalinfo/eula").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/users/uploadFile/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/users/sendEmail").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/legalinfo/privacy").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/changeuserpassword").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/forgotmypassword").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/validateEmail").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/checkToken").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/checkOTPToken").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

doing: `http://172.105.90.17:8081/actuator/health`

I get :

```
{
  "status": "UP"
}
```

but accessing : `http://172.105.90.17:8081/actuator/metrics`

I receive:

```
{
  "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

in the console:

```
2024-01-24 06:47:28.884 DEBUG [] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory@registerDependentBeans(952) - Autowiring by type from bean name 'webEndpointServletHandlerMapping' via factory method to bean named 'management.endpoints.web-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.WebEndpointProperties'
2024-01-24 06:47:28.884 DEBUG [] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory@registerDependentBeans(952) - Autowiring by type from bean name 'webEndpointServletHandlerMapping' via factory method to bean named 'environment'
2024-01-24 06:47:28.891 INFO  [] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver@<init>(58) - Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2024-01-24 06:47:28.905 DEBUG [] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory@getSingleton(225) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'controllerEndpointHandlerMapping'
```

Comment: Any Spring Security DEBUG log to provide? Also this class, does it have `@Configuration` or other annotation?

Comment: try `EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()` ...s. here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.security

Comment: You already have the correct exclusion, `.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()`, to disable auth for all actuator endpoints. The only thing that seems to be missing is the `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: [ health, metrics ]` config mentioned in `jccampanero`'s answer. Spring boot does seem to return a confusing 401/403 when trying to access an actuator endpoint that is not exposed at all, with security enabled. I would assume, with the current config, if you called the `/actuator/metrics` endpoint, with the expected auth headers, you'd get a 404.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question can be divided into this two problems:

1. **How to expose actuator endpoints and make them remotely accessible over HTTP?**
2. **How to make them accessible without need to login?**

**Solution of problem 1.**

By default only the `health` endpoint is enabled and exposed over HTTP. To include all available endpoints add this to `application.properties`:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

If you want the `shutdown` endpoint to be available as well add this:

```
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
```

If you want to change the default prefix which is `actuator` you can add this:

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/manage
```

Whith the above settings the URL for displaying all Spring beans will look like:

```
http://localhost:8081/manage/beans
```

**Solution of problem 2.**

If the Spring Boot Security is enabled (as in your case) then only `health` endpoint will be accessible without login. You can override this default behavior by adding `/manage/**` to the requestMatchers block. Something like this:

```java
    .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
        .requestMatchers("/manage/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
```

The above is not very nice. The prefix `manage` is hard coded here. What if somebody change the prefix in the `application.properties` later on?

It is better to use a dedicated factory class `EndpointRequest` instead. Leave the application specific `SecurityFilterChange` bean as it is and add another one just for the actuator:

```
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain actuatorFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.securityMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint().excluding(ShutdownEndpoint.class));
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }
```

In the above example all endpoints but the `shutdown` are accessible for everyone.

Please mind the `@Order` annotation. It is important because of use of SecurityMatcher.

On the server log you will see something similar to this:

```
EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 14 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/manage'
DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Will secure EndpointRequestMatcher includes=[*], excludes=[shutdown]...
DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Will secure any request with...
```

Based on [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints).

Answer (score 3):

According to your log output it seems that only the `health` actuator endpoint is exposed in your app:

```
2024-01-24 06:47:28.891 INFO  [] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver@<init>(58) - Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
```

As stated in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.exposing) when describing how endpoints are exposed:

> *By default, only the health endpoint is exposed over HTTP and JMX.* Since
> Endpoints may contain sensitive information, you should carefully consider
> when to expose them.

Although, as explained in other answers and in the [Spring documentation itself](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.security), further security configuration could be required, to solve the problem, as a first step, consider include `metrics` as one of the web exposed endpoints.

As usually in Spring, you can do it using configuration properties, in this case, assuming you are using yaml:

```yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "health,metrics"
```

Or, equivalently, if you are using Java properties:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,metrics
```

Comment: This should work, you should see 
'Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'

Also worth to mention that you can remove 
`.requestMatchers("/actuator/metrics").permitAll()` as it's already taken care of by
`.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @ŁukaszMączka. Yes, I completely agree with you, the `.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()` configuration already matches `.requestMatchers("/actuator/metrics").permitAll()`; as a consequence, `.requestMatchers("/actuator/metrics").permitAll()` can be safely removed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to expose your actuator endpoints via `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include` property in the **application.properties**.

`/actuator/health` is exposed by default. To enable other actuator endpoints to be accessed, then please add them via the above property.
Otherwise, the incoming request to access the actuator endpoint needs to be authenticated.

Just add the below line in the **application.properties** to enable access to actuator endpoints. For example: I have added `/health`, `/metrics`, `/beans` to the property. This will make sure that only these three actuator endpoints are accessible only.

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health, metrics, beans
```

**Note:** You can granularly control on which actuator endpoints to provide access by putting the endpoint name in the above property.

**Or**

If you want to give access to all the actuator endpoints, then do this:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

You can also use `management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude` property.

**For example:**

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=health, beans
```

-> By above property, you say that you want to expose all the endpoints excluding `/health`, `/beans`.

There are lots of options. Just play with these properties to understand the usage and then add it to your codebase to see if it works properly.

Refer to the spring docs for actuator endpoints [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.11.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html).

> These properties work with both Spring Boot **2.x** and **3.x** as
> tested.

**Note:** Remove this line `.requestMatchers("/actuator/metrics").permitAll()` from your code. Just that this line `.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()` is more than sufficient.

Sample Output:

http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics

[image]

http://localhost:8080/actuator/health

[image]

http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/application.ready.time

[image]

http://localhost:8080/actuator/beans

[image]

See if this information helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, late, but quick and simple:

#### Starter

https://start.spring.io/#!dependencies=web,actuator,security

#### Demo

Spring boot app, controller, security config:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    static class DemoController {
        @GetMapping
        public String forbidden() {
            return "forbidden";
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    static class SecurityConfig {
        @Bean
        @Order(1) // ..restricted (non-lowest priority)
        SecurityFilterChain actuatorSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.securityMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()); //.. to actuator requests
            http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.anyRequest().permitAll()); // ..restrict/allow as see fit.
            return http.build();
        }

        @Bean // "normal" security chain ...
        SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
            // ... as see fit.
            http
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                            .anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .formLogin(withDefaults());
            return http.build();
        }
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

#### Results

The sample web app in being restricted for `/*`, while allowing requests to all actuator endpoints (by default `/actuator/*`).

Works also well, when `server.port=8081`...

#### Refs

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.security (and parent)
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity_instances

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/api/actuator/metrics/**");
}
```

Comment: the same result

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ..antMatcher is a correct solution approach, but the "value" has to match.. (`"/actuator/**"`?)

Answer (score 0):

you should add this code:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(
  ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.authorizeExchange()
      .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
      .anyExchange().authenticated()
      .and().build();
}
```

for more info visite the link below:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators

Comment: 'authorizeExchange()' is deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal

Answer (score 0):

Reading "[Spring Boot 3.3 / Production-ready Features / Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.3.x/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.security)", only `/health` is exposed if you do not customize the security settings.
If Spring Security is on the classpath, and you have not defined a custom `SecurityFilterChain`, Spring Boot automatically secures all Actuator endpoints except `/health`.

So if you define a custom `SecurityFilterChain`, Spring Boot's autoconfiguration for Actuator security is disabled, giving you full control over the security rules.

Using `EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()`, as commented, is a convenient way to apply security configurations specifically to all Actuator endpoints
If you have a custom `SecurityFilterChain` (as in your original setup), you need to explicitly configure security rules for Actuator endpoints, as Spring Boot will not apply its default Actuator security configuration.

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    // other beans and configurations

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        // Custom security for Actuator endpoints
        http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().permitAll()); // or .hasRole("ENDPOINT_ADMIN")

        // Security rules for other endpoints
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> {
            requests.antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll();
            // other antMatchers
            requests.anyRequest().authenticated();
        });

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

`EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()` is used to apply custom security rules to Actuator endpoints.
You can choose to either permit all requests to Actuator endpoints or restrict them to users with a specific role (e.g., `ENDPOINT_ADMIN`).

---

You can also restrict unauthenticated access to only specific Actuator endpoints like `/actuator/metrics`, especially in scenarios where you want to expose certain metrics for monitoring purposes but keep other Actuator endpoints secure.

To modify your `SecurityFilterChain` configuration to allow unauthenticated access only to `/actuator/metrics` while securing other Actuator endpoints, you can adjust the [`authorizeHttpRequests` method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html#request-authorization-architecture):

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    // other beans and configurations

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        // Custom security rules
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .requestMatchers("/actuator/metrics").permitAll() // Unauthenticated access only to /actuator/metrics
            .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").authenticated()  // Secure other Actuator endpoints
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            // other antMatchers
            .anyRequest().authenticated());

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The call to `.requestMatchers("/actuator/metrics").permitAll()` allows unauthenticated access specifically to the `/actuator/metrics` endpoint.
The other call to `.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").authenticated()` secures all other Actuator endpoints, requiring authentication.
The rest of the application's endpoints are configured as you wanted them, e.g., permitting all requests to `/api/auth/**`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may expose spring boot actuator endpoints by using a different HTTP port like 8082 or others.

You can set the management.server.port property to change the HTTP port, as shown in the following example:

```xml
management.server.port=8082
```